# Anonymous account that sticks through app uninstall/reinstall

Tags: android, ios, authentication

I’ve seen apps where users can create a guest account (anonymous) without password, and when they delete the game and reinstall it, they’re still logged in to their guest account.

I’ve also seen some apps where this situation would create a new guest account every time. I’d like to avoid this in my app but I don’t know how to.

Anyone knows how this is done?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) will help you

Answer (score 0):

So you want to generate userId and persist it through app reinstalls. In android I heard that there is no problem to get unique identifier. In iOS you can use framework like JNKeychain. Then you generate unique value. In obj-c you may wish to use such code.

```
NSString* deviceId = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey: @"deviceId"];

if (!deviceId)
{
    if (![JNKeychain saveValue: [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey: @"deviceId"])
    {
        deviceId = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    }
    else
    {
        deviceId = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey: @"deviceId"];
    }
}
```